# ASR 100X series hardware redundancy?

Tags: cisco, router, network-core, redundancy, cisco-asr

I have very little knowledge of the Cisco ASR series. We are planning to buy a ASR 1001X series router, but I have a  question related to hardware redundancy.

Do I need to buy two Cisco ASR series routers, or will a single ASR be enough, and it will provide all kinds of redundancy?

I am clueless about this hardware. Please advice me how I can make low cost advantage of an ASR, because buying two routers is expensive.

Comment: This information is freely available on Cisco's website, you should share what research or info you have already as it looks like you haven't even bothered to check for your self.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can search Cisco for this type of information. For instance, the Cisco document, [High Availability Overview](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/asr1000/configuration/guide/chassis/asrswcfg/High_Availability.html#pgfId-1058882), has a table:

> **Hardware Redundancy Overview on the Cisco ASR 1000 Series Routers**
>
> Some models of the Cisco ASR 1000 Series Routers offer hardware
>   redundancy within the same Cisco ASR 1000 Series Router through the
>   following methods:
>
> - Allowing two Route Processors (RPs) in the same Cisco ASR 1000 Series    Router
> - Allowing two Enhanced Services Processors (ESPs) in the same Cisco    ASR 1000 Series Router
>
> No hardware redundancy is supported for the following hardware:
>
> - SPA interface processors (SIPs)—A SIP must be reloaded, and traffic    briefly interrupted, for a SIP upgrade to complete.
> - Shared port adapters (SPAs)—A SPA must be reloaded, which will    briefly interrupt traffic to that SPA, for a SPA software subpackage
>     update to complete.
>
> Hardware redundancy on the Cisco ASR 1000 Series Routers gives users
>   the following benefits:
>
> - A failover option—If a processor fails, the standby processor    immediately becomes the active processor with little or no delay. The 
>     failover happens completely within the same router, so a second
>     standby router is not needed.
> - No downtime upgrades—Using features like ISSU, a software upgrade can    be handled on the standby processor while the active processor 
>     continues normal operation.
>
> Hardware redundancy is available on the Cisco ASR 1006 Router only at
>   this time.
>
> provides a hardware redundancy overview.
>
> [image]

As you can see, it depends on the particular router model and part.

Comment: Thanks, Cisco document is little cryptic for people like me (fresher). As per your link ASR does support built-in hardware failover right? so i don't need to buy two ASR and do redundancy.

Comment: If you look, the ASR1006 has the capability of redundancy (you still need to buy the expensive, redundant parts) in the processing, but the I/O doesn't provide redundancy from a hardware perspective.

Comment: We are planning to buy ASR 1002 Routes, look like it doesn't have built-in Hardware redundancy.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: so which router we should buy? ASR 1000 or ASR 1006 for hardware redundancy?  1006 is way out from our budget :(

Comment: Just buying an ASR1006 doesn't automatically give you redundancy; you still need to buy the expensive, redundant parts. You can get a pair of ASR1002s for about half the price you would pay for a redundant ASR1006, but they are not as modular. It depends on how much the redundancy and flexibility are worth. It has been our experience that you are far more likely to lose a circuit than the router. You can buy one router and SmartNet with a two-hour turnaround, but if it is important enough to have redundant hardware, you will pay for it.